# I have a question on FTIR spectroscopy; please help

Tags: spectroscopy

1. In FTIR spectroscopy, is it that both the background and the sample interferograms are converted to spectra by the application of Fourier transform and then the spectrum obtained from the background interferogram is subtracted from the spectrum obtained from the sample interferogram so as to identify the absorption properties of the sample?
2. Would you please help me understand where the formula for modulation frequency in the interferometer (2 * velocity of the movable mirror * wavenumber of a given radiation)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.